# How to pass a file from the client-side to the backend using Vue and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue with NodeJs, Vuetify and Express. I load user's file with the Vuetify's component:

```
<v-file-input
v-model="documentFile.value"
:error-messages="documentFile.errors"
accept="application/pdf"
/>
```

Then I want to pass the file (that is stored in `this.documentFile.value`) to my backend, so it will upload it to the Drive. I pass the data using Vue Recourse:

```
var params = {
    "data":                 this.data.value
    "score":                this.score.value
    //"document_file":        this.documentFile.value,
    "comments":             this.comments.value
};

Vue.http.put('http://localhost:8081/api/new-document', {params: params}).then(
  response => {
      console.log("Sent data");
  }, response => {
      console.error(response);
  }
);
```

In my NodeJS backend I have:

```
router.put('/new-document', function(request, response) {
  console.log("New Document");
  console.log(request.query);

  // Upload file to drive
  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URI
  );
  response.status(200).send({});
});
```

How can I pass the file from the client to the backend?

**EDIT**: If I uncomment `document_file`, and try to print `request.query`, it prints:

```
{
  data: { age: '27', name: 'robert' },
  comments: 'comment',
  "score": 89
}
```

For some reason, it ignores the `document_file`.

The code in my `server.js`:

```
const cors       = require("cors");
const express    = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const routes     = require('./routes');

const path = __dirname + '/../public/';

console.log("STARTED");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path));

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8080"
};



app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// map requests to routes
app.use('/api', routes);


// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Comment: What is the result of`console.log(request.query); // >`?

Comment: @RotikenGisa If I uncomment the `document_file` line, it does not pass it to the `request.query`. But it pass all the others.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the file from the client to the backend, use the `new FormData()` object.

In your case you can do something like:

```
var params = new FormData();
params.append('data', this.data.value);
params.append('score', this.score.value);
params.append('document_file', this.documentFile.value)
params.append('comments', this.comments.value);
```

Then pass the object either using axios or Vue Recourse as you would like.

```
axios.put('url', params)
```

**EDIT**

You can use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to upload your files either locally or to the cloud. In your case, you can upload to `GoogleStorage`

```
const multer  = require('multer')

// You can start off by testing local uploads
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

// then use this to upload to Google Storage
const multerGoogleStorage = require('multer-google-storage')

const uploadHandler = multer({
  storage: multerGoogleStorage.storageEngine({
    autoRetry: true,
    bucket: '<your_storage_bucket_name>',
    projectId: '<your_project_ID>',
    keyFilename: '<your_path_to_key_file>',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, `/<some_prefix_of_choice>/${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`)
    }
  })
})
```

Upload the file either to local or Google Cloud

```
// local uploads (destination projectRoot/uploads)
router.put('/new-document', upload.single('document_file'), async (request, response) => {});
// or GoogleStorage
router.put('/new-document', uploadHandler.single('document_file'), async (request, response) => {});
```

Multiple files can also be uploaded

```
app.put('/new-document', upload.array('document_files', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})
```

The document file(s) can then be accessible on the Express server using

```
request.file
```

You can the upload the file. The other form objects can also be accessible through `request.body` e.g.

```
request.body.data
```

Comment: I tried both with `axios` and `VueResouse`. I get `request.query={}`, `request.body={}` and `request.document_file=undefined`. Why is that?

Comment: 1. Does your Express app use `app.use(express.json())` or `const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser())`? 2. You access the `document_file` through `request.file` not `request.document_file`

Comment: I use `const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser()); app.use('/api', routes);`. Also, tried `request.file` but it's undefined as well (what if I need to pass two files?)

Comment: @vesii I have updated the answer using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)